# Are there macros for SIMD instruction sets?

Tags: c#, simd, intrinsics

Are there any macros that we can use for instruction set detection?

I know that we have the runtime ones:

```cs
if (Avx.IsSupported)
{
//...
}
```

but do we have defined symboles for that e.g.

```cs
#if AVX
//...
#endif
```

And if there are none, can we create ones or do we have a workaround for that?

### NOTE

- while playing with decompiler I found a weird "recursion ". But I think the ILSpy missed here.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static 
    bool get_IsSupported () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x142fa4
    // Code size 6 (0x6)
    .maxstack 8

    // return IsSupported;
    IL_0000: call bool System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Avx::get_IsSupported()
    IL_0005: ret
} // end of method Avx::get_IsSupported
```

- Also when I looked into a simple `asm` code I noticed the following:

```cs
public int F() 
{
    if (Avx.IsSupported)
        return 0;
    if (Avx2.IsSupported)
        return 1;

    return 2;
}
```

**asm**

```
Program.F()
    L0000: xor eax, eax
    L0002: ret
```

As you can see it somehow figured out that Avx is supported and didn't include the branches. Is this a normal and well defined behaviour?

Comment: The problem with compiler directives is that they are checked compile time (c# => MSIL) so you need to know which target system you're compiling for.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen doesn't MSVC have a macro `__AVX__`? How do they predict?

Comment: @Hrant C/C++ AFAIK is compiled per platform producing an executable, while for C#  result of compilation is an IL code which will be processed later (via JIT) on the client machine

Comment: @harold random question: If I had multiple `if`s that check the same thing every time, wouldn't  that be less efficient than a macro that simply gets the cpuid once? (I'm assuming that's what you mean with *conditional compilation with macros*) ... I guess I could have stored the bool and reused it.

Comment: @GuruStron that actually sounds logical to me. Thanks

Comment: `Is this a normal and well defined behaviour?` Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Avx.IsSupported`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx.issupported?view=net-5.0) is a *run-time* feature because it needs to dynamically detect the capabilities of the target CPU where your code is actually being run.

On the other hand, [`#if`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) is a *compile-time* feature, conditional compilation. It's not really useful to have an `AVX` conditional compilation symbol and then just presume for the target CPU to do have support for AVX. It is simply better to check on run-time and behave accordingly.

However, should you really need to use conditional compilation, you can always declare your own symbol.

Comment: I think VS has `__AVX__` macro for C/C++. How does that one work?

Comment: @Hrant It doesn't test for support, it is a build configuration.  Think along the lines of .NET's `AnyCPU` vs x86 vs x64 builds... A C++ project could have configurations for x86, x64 without AVX, x64 with AVX, etc.   You certainly could do the same thing in a C# project, but then you'd need logic in the installer to decide whether to copy your with-AVX or without AVX files to the computer.  (And C++ can also do runtime checks, usually handled by setting function pointers after doing the test, so the individual functions come in two versions and never have to do the runtime check themselves)

Comment: @Hrant: C++ is ahead-of-time compiled to machine code.  If you build with `/arch:AVX` to tell the compiler to make code that assumes AVX support, it will pre-define `__AVX__` so your C++ code can also assume AVX support and do things like using intrinsics.  This is the most efficient way to compile if you don't care about running on machines without AVX.  (e.g. if you're building an executable for your cloud server.  But unfortunately MSVC has no equivalent of `gcc -O3 -march=native` to enable use of everything the build-host supports; it's designed around a one-binary-everywhere model.)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Avx.IsSupported)
{
}
else
{
}
```

is the correct way to achieve what you want:

> The IsSupported checks are treated as runtime constants by the JIT (when optimizations are enabled) and so you do not need to cross-compile to support multiple different ISAs, platforms, or architectures. Instead, you just write your code using if-statements and the unused code paths (any code path which
> is not executed, due to the condition for the branch being false or an earlier branch being taken instead) are dropped from the generated code (the native >assembly code generated by the JIT at runtime).

[https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/#:~:text=The%C2%A0IsSupported%C2%A0checks%20are,by%20the%20JIT%20at%20runtime](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/#:%7E:text=The%C2%A0IsSupported%C2%A0checks%20are,by%20the%20JIT%20at%20runtime)).